# Angular JS Passing $scope to Modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, parameter-passing

http://jsfiddle.net/dwmkerr/8MVLJ/

I'm trying to experiment from the sample above. My problem is that the modal cannot seem to read anything from the $scope that called it.

Javascript

```
$scope.sampleTest = "SAMPLE TEXT"; // additional code
$scope.show = function() {

    ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: "ModalController"
    }).then(function(modal) {
        modal.element.modal();
        modal.close.then(function(result) {
            $scope.message = "You said " + result;
        });
    });
};
```

HTML

```
<p>It's your call...{{sampleText}}</p>
```

The modal only shows "It's your call..." instead of "It's your call... SAMPLE TEXT"

Is there anything I'm missing out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the modal has its own controller (which is separate from the controller that called the modal), you would need to pass any variables you need into the resolve function of the modal.

Then in the modal controller, you would need to add the resolved object to the scope so it is able to be bound in the modal's view

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, I tried using the same controller but the modal can't seem to read anything from the scope. I'll try what you suggested though. Cheers mate!

Comment: Rock on! The resolve function did it well, thanks mate!

Comment: hi just a quick question, how do you "add the resolved object to the scope"

Comment: oops nevermind i found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576454/pass-parameter-to-modal

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Great and flexible solution but I've to ask, How can I pass a data from modal controller to another controller?