# Pass selected argument in modal dialog of angular in seperate controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I want to pass selected item in modal dialog using $modal directive of angular, i know its quite simple but i am new angular, any help in this regard would be appreciate-able, I already spent 3 4 hours on it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please share your outcome of those 3-4 hours (your code). And read this -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576454/pass-parameter-to-modal/22132677#22132677