# error with using resolve angular-bootstrap-ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am having difficulties combining both the editing of a current contact and the creation of a new contact. I am able to edit the contact that I click on, however, when I try and click on add new address the following error message -

```
angular.js:13424 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=editIndexProvider%20%3C-%20editIndex%20%3C-%20ModalCtrl
```

This is due to using `resolve` based on the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576454/pass-parameter-to-modal)

**Factory**

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap']);

app.factory('addressFactory', function(){
    var addressFactory = {};
    addressFactory.addressBook = [];

addressFactory.saveAddress = function(name, address){
    addressFactory.addressBook.push({
        name: name, 
        address: address 
    });
};

addressFactory.updateAddress = function(name, address, index){
    addressFactory.addressBook[index] = {
        name: name, 
        address: address
    };
};
    return addressFactory;
})
```

**CONTROLLERS**

```
.app.controller('testCtrl', ['$uibModal', 'addressFactory', function ($uibModal, addressFactory) {

    var testCtrl = this;
    this.addressBook = addressFactory.addressBook;

    this.open = function () {
        touchnoteCtrl.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/add-address.html',
            controller: 'ModalCtrl',
            controllerAs:'ctrl'
        });
    }

    this.openEdit = function(index) {
        touchnoteCtrl.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/edit-address.html',
            controller: 'ModalCtrl',
            controllerAs:'ctrl',
            resolve: {
                editIndex: function () {
                    return index;
                }
           }
        });
    }
}])

.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$uibModalInstance','addressFactory','editIndex', function ($uibModalInstance,addressFactory, editIndex) {

    this.addressBook = addressFactory.addressBook;

    this.saveAddress = function( name, address) {
         addressFactory.saveAddress( name, address);
         $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }

    this.getIndex = editIndex;
    console.log(this.getIndex)

    this.updateAddress = function(name, address, index) {
         addressFactory.updateAddress( name, address, index);
    }

    this.cancelAddress = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

}]);
```

**HTML**

**home.html**

```
 <a ng-click="ctrl.open()">Enter new address</a>

 <div ng-repeat="contact in ctrl.addressBook track by $index"> 
    <p class="contactName">{{contact.name}}</p>
    <p class="contactAddress">{{contact.address}}</p>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.openEdit($index)">Edit Contact</button>
 </div>
```

**form.html**

```
<form>
     <input ng-model="ctrl.name" type="text">        
     <input ng-model="ctrl.address" type="text">
</form>
```

**edit-address.html**

```
<h3>Edit address</h3>
<div ng-include="'app/views/partials/form.html'"></div>
<div>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.cancelAddress()">Cancel</button>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.updateAddress(ctrl.name, ctrl.address, ctrl.getIndex)">Save</button>
</div>
```

**add-address.html**

```
<h3>Add address</h3>
<div ng-include="'app/views/partials/form.html'"></div>
<div>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.cancelAddress()">Cancel</button>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.addAddress(ctrl.name, ctrl.address)">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if you just skipped it for brevity but `touchnoteCtrl` is not declared in `testCtrl` . Otherwise can't see much wrong with the use of `resolve` here. `ModalCtrl` isn't referenced anywhere else on the page is it?

Comment: @rom99 sorry, I have updated the name of the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same `ModalCtrl` for both the `open` and the `openEdit` function. The `open` function does not have a resolve parameter. This way, angular cannot resolve the injected `editIndex`. Try this:

```
this.open = function () {
    touchnoteCtrl.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/add-address.html',
        controller: 'ModalCtrl',
        controllerAs:'ctrl',
        resolve: {
            editIndex: function () {
                return undefined;
            }
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: This works a treat! You're a genius, and a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply miss a module dependency to `angular.ui.bootstrap`...

Comment: I have added the dependency in the `app.module`